# Git repository not updating

Tags: windows, git, ubuntu

**Background:**

- In a network, there are two PCs, one using Windows 7 and other using Ubuntu 12.10 as their OSs.
- Both have Git installed. Windows one from http://git-scm.com/download/win and Ubuntu one from `apt-get install git-core`.
- Ubuntu PC has Samba configured so that it is possible to access Windows PCs in the network using their hostnames.
- Using `git clone http://windowspc/system/.git`, it was possible to create a clone of the repository from Windows PC in the Ubuntu PC.

**Problem:**

- Changes are made into the code in the Windows PC. Commands `git add .` and `git commit -m"Comment."` are issued in the Git prompt in the Windows PC.
- Back in Ubuntu PC, when `git fetch` and `git pull` commands are issues, the message `Already up-to-date` is presented.
- However, none of the changes made in the Windows PC appear in the Ubuntu PC.

**Question**

- What should be the path to be taken to get updated files from Windows PC to the Ubuntu PC?

Comment: Try cloning `http://windowspc/system` (without the `.git`)

Comment: @VonC: I did try that. But it won at least make a clone, let alone updating it. To make a clone we must use `.git`.

Comment: Are you on the same branch for both repositories?

Comment: @rlegendi: The repository in the Ubuntu PC is a clone of the one in Windows PC. And both of them have only one branch (I am still trying to set this up.), which is "master".

Comment: Are you sure you are not using hard links where all the repositories are really just links to the same git repository.  Make sure you clone with the --no-hardlinks.  If this helps please separate your repositories so that you have one core bare repository since it is more flexible. (See my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm used to doing a 'git push' after doing a commit.

I would create a bare repository that is shared by both your windows machine and your Ubuntu machine.  I would then amend your instructions to include a 'git push' after you commit your changes.  You could then use gitk to make sure that everything is up to date.  BTW I find that the best way to access git under Windows is by using cygwin.

My method of doing a creation of a bare repository that is shared between Windows and Unix/Linux is:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/source
git clone --bare --no-hardlinks -l . /cygdrive/s/shareddir/source.git
```

To connect the new bare repository back to the original source code:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/source
git remote add origin /cygdrive/s/shareddir/source.git
git remote update
git remote -v
git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```